# How can I create a sitemap for each content type?

Tags: xml-sitemap

How can I create a sitemap for each content type?

Answer (score 1):

There's now the module to do that: [XML Sitemap per node type](https://www.drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap_nodetype)

> The XML Sitemap Per Node Type module provides the additional context for XML sitemap module that allows creating sitemaps per content type.

Answer (score 0):

The XML Sitemap doesn't support creating multiple arbitrary sitemaps (e.g. *a sitemap with only content type X*) . What it does support is different *contexts* in which it makes sense to have a isolated content sitemap (e.g. a [Google News sitemap](https://support.google.com/news/publisher/answer/74288?hl=en) or sitemap in a different language). This needs to be supported at a module level however.

What you can do is exclude content types from inclusion (under the content type edit page on **admin/structure/types/manage**) in the default sitemap.

Comment: Ok Shawn,That's fine.I'm agree with you.But I have created a rss feed view and filter it by content type X.It's showing visual xml data.Can I convert it into html or something make it to user friendly?

Comment: If you're using Views to generate the RSS then the answer is yes, but that's a different question that falls out of the scope of XML sitemap. DA isn't a forum, you should ask it as another question if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 8+, the [Simple XML Sitemap module](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_sitemap) supports the creation of multiple sitemaps out of the box.

It supports most entity types, and it can be extended relatively easily with custom code.